# Can I connect mysql client to a mariadb server?

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I am new to databases, so I might have done something very simple wrong.

I cannot connect to my Mariadb server via my mysql client. Is this possible at all?

```
cmd> mysql -h 192.168.0.17 -u root -P 3306
```

gives me an error:

> ERROR 2013 (HY000): Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 0

On my host machine, I have mysql with version

```
cmd> mysql -V
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.6.10, for Win64 (x86_64)
```

and on my VM, I have an ubuntu server

```
$ mysql -V
mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.3.23-MariaDB, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 5.2
```

and my config on VM:

```
$ cat /etc/mysql/my.cnf.dpkg-new | head -n 20 | tail -n 7
```

```
# This will be passed to all mysql clients
# It has been reported that passwords should be enclosed with ticks/quotes
# escpecially if they contain "#" chars...
# Remember to edit /etc/mysql/debian.cnf when changing the socket location.
[client]
port        = 3306
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
```

Ping is OK:

```
cmd> ping 192.168.0.17

Pinging 192.168.0.17 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 192.168.0.17: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.0.17: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.0.17: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.0.17: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64

Ping statistics for 192.168.0.17:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 0ms, Maximum = 0ms, Average = 0ms
```

Comment: `/etc/mysql/my.cnf.dpkg-new`: This file is not used. You need to rename it to have simply the .cnf extension, or presumably, there is already a file with that name. dpkg-new is created by the package manager when it has updates to the .cnf file, but won't do it because that file has been manually modified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anyway, I fixed the problem via

```
MariaDB [(none)]> Grant All Privileges ON *.* to 'remoteroot'@'192.168.0.15' Identified By '123456';
MariaDB [(none)]> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

where `192.168.0.15` is the host machine IP.

Then connected via

```
cmd> mysql -h 192.168.0.17 -u remoteroot -P 3306 -p
```

Looks like working.

Still concerned some features face problems.

Comment: `FLUSH PRIVILEGES` isn't required for `grant`. Also better get used to creating users separately as the combined `create user`/ `grant` syntax is going away. Why are you concerted about exposure on your lan address?